# Why doesn't window onload bound in closure always run

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something along the lines of the following code where I bind a window onload inside a closure. The window onload only seems to fire randomly or when the page takes a long time to load

```js
$(() => {
  console.log('test');
  // code that needs to run when document is ready

  window.onload = () => {
    console.log('test 1');
    // need this code to use some variables set in code above but only fire when all images have loaded so offsets are correct
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Why doesn't the onload fire every time the page loads?

Comment: $(() => {}) will trigger when the document is ready

Comment: Yes I know - I have code above the onload that needs to run on document ready

Comment: ok have found a duplicate answer based on the below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if you have a short DOM load the window.onload can be fired on the exact moment as document.ready. Thus, the onload listener will not be attached in time in the ready closure.

Comment: is there a way to tell if onload has already fired? so I can either bind an onload or run the function directly?

Comment: You can check by document.readyState == 'complete'

Comment: Cool just found a duplicate based on this, thanks.  Will accept when it lets me